# Python Send email from a delegated account

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, gmail-api

I am using python to send a scorecard to users on a monthly basis. I would like to use the delegated Gmail account to send email to users. Attached images for your reference.

I can send email to users using my personal account. But I can't send email to users using the Delegated account.

Attached error message screenshot here. I google error message and I couldn't find any posts related to the error message.

[Gmail Delegated Account Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tPZI.png)

[Python Script Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExUV0.png)

[Python Error Message Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sF7My.png)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to let less secure apps access your account.

See the related Google answer: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Btw, that's written in the "support.google.com" link.